# copy and paste to all files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a sheet from one file and then paste it to an established tab in about 6 files in an established folder. I have this code, but it only works for the first file in the folder. It is also creating a blank workbook for some reason. Any suggestions?

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

Dim wbk As Workbook 
Dim Filename As String
Dim FirstFile As String 
Dim FileDirectory As String
Dim x As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("test.xlsx")


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    .Title = "Please select a folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You did not select a folder"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        FileDirectory = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End If

End With

Set wbk = Workbooks.Add


Filename = Dir(FileDirectory)
FirstFile = Filename



Do Until Filename = ""

    Dim new_wb As Workbook
Set new_wb = Workbooks.Open(FileDirectory & Filename)



If FirstFile = Filename Then

    x.Sheets("report").UsedRange.Copy

    new_wb.Sheets("roster").Range("a1").PasteSpecial




End If


new_wb.Close savechanges:=True
Filename = Dir

Loop

MsgBox "All store totals have been added"

End Sub
```

Comment: (a) Your line `If FirstFile = Filename Then` is specifically telling the macro to only do the copy/paste if it is the first file in the folder.  (b) I'm not sure why it would create a blank workbook - what is the filename being given to the blank workbook?

Comment: (b) Your line `Set wbk = Workbooks.Add` will create a new blank workbook. Since there is no reference to wbk in the following lines, you could probably just delete this line.

Comment: I did figure this out last night. I also added a little wrinkle for the actions being completed. I am new to the sight, so if someone could let me know how to add the updated code, I will. It maxes out the characters for this reply when I try to copy it here.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub LoopThroughFiles_Paste_Roster()

Dim wbk As Workbook 'New workbook the data is added to
Dim Filename As String
Dim FirstFile As String
Dim FileDirectory As String
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("Copy Doc 1")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("Copy Doc 2")

'display the folder picker dialog box so user can select a folder
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    .Title = "Please select a folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You did not select a folder"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        FileDirectory = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End If
    
End With



'retrieve the name of the first file in the folder using Dir
Filename = Dir(FileDirectory)
FirstFile = Filename

'Loop through all the files in the folder
'open the file

Do Until Filename = ""

  
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(FileDirectory & Filename, UpdateLinks:=False, Password:="Password123")
    
    With wbk
    
        x.Sheets("report").UsedRange.Copy

        wbk.Sheets("roster").Range("a1").PasteSpecial
        
         y.Sheets("Setup").UsedRange.Copy

        wbk.Sheets("PTO Taken and Req").Range("a1").PasteSpecial
        
           
       End With
    
'save and close the file
'get the next file in the folder
    wbk.Close savechanges:=True
    Filename = Dir

Loop

MsgBox "All pages have been updated"

End Sub
```